# Lookup table in JAI

Tags: java, jai

I am looking at an existing Java **CT image** display program here. I try to understand how the **Lookup Table** works in **JAI**.

From the [JAI guide, section 7.6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7284-JAI-1.0.1-guide-doc-oth-JPR), I read this:

*The input pixel values acts as an address to the lookup table inputs. Each location in the lookup table  stores the desired output value for that particular address.*

We only need grey scale display, so we have a lookup table of size 256. But the *input pixel values* which are **our original image pixels** can be **negative** sometimes. Then how can I use them as index/address?

I can shift the data to make sure all values are positive but I will lose the original data values then.

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if JAI would actually try to use a negative pixel value directly as an index. I would expect it to at least use unsigned-conversion (i.e. `pixel&255`) when indexing.

If JAI doesn't do the right thing I think you can create the lookup table with a negative offset, like -128, so that negative pixels are looked up in the first half of the table and positive ones in the second half.